# Big Batch Command in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I need to execute a considerably-size insertion operation from my Java-based web app. Due to the potential size of the operation I'm using a dynamically generated `OCommmandScript` which I am then executing using

```
orientGraph.command(new OCommandScript("sql", sql)).execute(params);
```

Now, in the typical scenario, `sql` is big (~5000 characters), `params` contains about 20k entries and OrientDB takes more that one minute to execute the script. This is far more than I can afford, as this is executed in the context of a REST request. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way I can speed up this operation for a large number of insertions?

Comment: We can't comment without knowing more about the SQL and table structure.  How does a web page generate 20,000 entries?

Comment: It's not a webpage, it's actually, and as I said before, a REST API where users are allowed to upload an arbitrarily large list of entities which correspond to graph vertexes.